# Jenkins pipeline how to change to another folder and run npm tests

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Currently, I am using Jenkins pipeline script.

For running my tests, I need to access my code which is sitting on the desktop.

I tried this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "node"}

  stages {
    stage('Tests') {
      steps {
        sh 'cd users/tests/'
        sh 'npm run shopfloor.shopfloor'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How I can change to my test folder and then run "npm run test"

I tried the answer below however i am getting this error now:

```
Running in users/tests/
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
+ npm run shopfloor.shopfloor
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_cwd
    at process.wrappedCwd (internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state.js:129:28)
    at process.cwd (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:10:19)
    at Conf.loadPrefix (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/load-prefix.js:46:24)
    at load_ (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:109:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:96:5)
    at Conf.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ConfigChain._resolve (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:281:34)
    at ConfigChain.add (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:259:10)
    at Conf.add (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:338:27)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/Users/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:314:25)
internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state.js:129
    cachedCwd = rawMethods.cwd();
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the agent?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`dir` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) to switch the directory and execute the commands in that context:

```java
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "node"}

  stages {
    stage('Tests') {
      steps {
        dir('users/tests/') { // <<------------
          sh 'npm run shopfloor.shopfloor'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried the answer but now i am getting an error. I edited in my question above

Answer (score 2):

Please try once using double quotes.

```
dir("folder")
```

in groovy Single quotes are a standard Java String while Double quotes are a templatable String.